# サンプルコード内の"<"の表示方法について

Tags: サポート, コード整形

別の質問をしたいのですが、
サンプルコードを書いているときに、実際のコードが反映されていないことに気が付き、
それについてまずは質問させていただいています。

実際には、
"for i:=0; i<10; i++ { continue }"
のようにfor loopを使って質問をしたいのです。
しかしこれを`<pre></pre>`の中に書きますと、"<"以下の文字が消えてしまいます。
（バグる理由はわかります。）

以下例:

for i:=0; i

どのようにしたら、`<pre></pre>`の中に"<"を表示できるようになるのでしょうか？
ものすごく初歩的なことだと思いますが、
stackoverflowの初心者のため、ご教授をお願いします。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

該当コード部分を選択状態にして`{ }`ボタンを押して下さい。
(この場合、preタグ自体は自動的に適用されるので自分で書く必要はありません）

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。<pre>{}</pre>を押してから、その中に式を書き込んでいました。これが原因だと思われます。本当に助かりました。

Answer (score 3):

補足です。

このサイトでは質問や回答の本文をMarkdownで書くので、 `{}` を押した場合もMarkdownのコードブロックで整形されます。

何も選択していない時に `{}` を押した際に貼り付けられる以下のテキストですが、

```
    コードをここに入力
```

このように半角スペース4つでインデントすることでコードブロックになります。

文中やコメントでコードを書くときには `` `code` `` と書きます。詳しくはヘルプをご覧ください。

[Markdown 編集ヘルプ - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: ありがとうございます。そういうことだったんですね。勉強になりました。また、このサイトの初心者のため、質問の仕方・タグのつけ方等で間違っているところがあるかと思いますが、何卒寛大なご指導を今後ともよろしくお願いします。